# reformulate optimization problems as a standard least square problem

Tags: least-squares

[The first summand in the objective represents data fidelity; the second summand in the objective promotes smoothness.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGO9J.png)
I have no idea how to understand this equation. Why xhat will be equal to the sum of two constants? What does each part mean in this equation?